# Move raster image to overlay it perfectly on another same resolution raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, landsat, alignment

This question may seem strange at first, but what I need to do is to move a raster image over another raster image and align them perfectly. Both rasters have the very same size and resolution - one is a Landsat band and another is a product of bands analysis, **so this movement includes change of coordinates**.

Why are they in different places? In [Correcting Landsat images shifted by strangely high distance using ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226433) I said I have rasters straight from Earth Explorer covering some area that are misplaced from 100  m even up to 40 km (don't ask me why, sensor callibration?).

I will explain it by listing what I do:

1. For every image create an RGB composition (for better terrain recognition)
2. Choose one image as a reference one (which seems to be correct according to my GPS data)
3. Using ArcMap's [*Shift*](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/cad/georeferencingtoolbar-using-the-shift-tool.htm) tool I move each RGB image individually to it's correct place looking at the reference raster (RGB product only, bands are left untouched)
4. Now I would like to automatically apply movement of each band of each image to corresponding RGB image created from these bands (move them to their "correct place")
5. Afterwards I would use *Snap raster* option to align pixel misplacement if needed

Point **4.** is where I'm stuck. I would prefer not to have to use *Shift* tool for each image, because selecting correct X and Y shift is problematic if you don't remember by how much you have already moved the corresponding RGB.

Comment: This is a trivial exercise if you just use Python. It wouldn't be more than a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint given by [Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince), I wrote this really short Python script:

```
from osgeo import gdal

# here I open both files, the one to be shifted with '1' flag (write-permission)
band = gdal.Open("path to image I want to shift", 1)
reference = gdal.Open("path to reference image")

# read origin values from reference image
target = reference.GetGeoTransform()

# example origin values:
# (440025.0, 30.0, 0.0, 8923215.0, 0.0, -30.0)

# the main action - set new values to origin of band image (i.e. change position of its top-left corner)
band.SetGeoTransform(target)

# after shifting I found the projection gets reset and needs to be specified again, so I import it from reference image)
band.SetProjection(reference.GetProjection())
```

Put it in a loop to automate shifting of multiple images.